# weighting terms in solr text search

Tags: solr, weighted, text-search

I'm using solr to search for similar records in two restaurant datasets by getting a text field from a record of the first dataset and searching it in the second dataset. But there are some terms such as "bar", "pizza", "restaurant" that are so common in restaurants' names and cause so many false positive in the result. SO is there any way to down weight these terms effect in the search to avoid such wrong detection ?

Comment: That's the default behaviour - terms that occur often are scored lower than terms that are only present in a few documents. Do you have any small, reproducible examples of what you're thinking of? What does your query look like?

Comment: I want to match the restaurants in both datasets using their location and their names(which is a text field) such as >>>>>>     
Wow Chicken,51.055006--114.08585,Wow Chicken,51.05501--114.08585<<<<                  and this is my query >>>>  params={'q':"name: Wow CHicken",'wt':'json','rows':'10000000','fq':'{!geofilt sfield=location}','pt':str(51.055006)+","+str(-114.08585),'d':Dist}
'http://localhost:8983/solr/'+CoreName+'/select?'

Comment: But that query doesn't do what you think it does - `name: Wow Chicken` will, if anything, only search for `Wow` in the name field (and the space might confuse it as well), and `Chicken` in the default search field. `name:"Wow Chicken"` will do a proper phrase search to match the name like you probably intend.